# How to resolve this EAS Build Expo Doctor error - invalid: @expo/config-plugins@4.1.1?

Tags: expo, eas

Currently running Expo SDK 48. Am able to build successfully, but have not been able to resolve the following error from the Expo Doctor phase of EAS Build:

```
Issues:
[stderr] 
Expected package @expo/config-plugins@~6.0.0
[stderr] 
  Found invalid:
[stderr] 
    @expo/config-plugins@4.1.1
[stderr] 
    (for more info, run: npm why @expo/config-plugins)
Advice:
  • Upgrade dependencies that are using the invalid package versions.
```

If I run `npm ls @expo/config-plugins`, here is the result:

```
brainiac@1.0.0 /Users/sodiumhalogen/wip/megla-workshop-app
├── @expo/config-plugins@6.0.1
├─┬ @expo/config@8.0.2
│ └── @expo/config-plugins@6.0.1 deduped
├─┬ @expo/prebuild-config@6.0.1
│ └── @expo/config-plugins@6.0.1 deduped
├─┬ @expo/webpack-config@18.0.4
│ └─┬ @expo/config@6.0.20
│   └── @expo/config-plugins@4.1.1
└─┬ expo@48.0.15
  ├─┬ @expo/cli@0.7.1
  │ └── @expo/config-plugins@6.0.1 deduped
  └── @expo/config-plugins@6.0.1 deduped
```

It looks as if expo/webpack-config@18.04 is utilizing the older version 4.1.1 as a dependency. Is there a way to get EAS to use the expected version 6.0.0, instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this by removing the @expo/config-plugins package. Apparently, it is not needed in my project anymore since upgrading my project from Expo SDK 44 to 48. This article was shared with me by a user in the Expo forums and was helpful:

https://forums.expo.dev/t/android-production-build-failed-after-installing-ffmpeg-kit-react-native/70995

Comment: Hey, how did you remove @expo/config-plugins package? I mean did u run the following command : yarn remove @expo/config-plugins

Answer (score 0):

Run `npx expo install --check`
It will give you suggestion for which package do you need to update or downgrade.
For me, `npx expo install updates` was the solution.